# SPDT switch connected to 3 circuits

Tags: switches, toggle-switch

This is making me think more than it should, I'm obviously missing something obvious.

I have a hydraulic power pack and the control unit has stopped working, I need a quick and simple circuit to bypass the control unit.

It can only be operated by one momentary SPDT switch.

There's a signal for right, left and motor.
To turn right you need to supply 24v to open and motor
To turn left you need to supply 24v to close and motor

Every time I think of a circuit that works, I then draw it and realise I will send power to both the open and close supply on both switch presses.

What circuit will make this work?

[image]

Comment: What if you hardwire MOTOR to 24 volt and make the switch toggle 24V between OPEN and CLOSE?

Answer (score 1):

I knew I was missing something obvious, as soon as I posted the question it came to me. As far as I know, this circuit will work:

[image]

Comment: How much DC current does the motor pull? It seems like it will work, but you might need one hell of a diode there

Comment: It's done through a relay, the 3 signals came from a PCB with no major power components so can't see it being a problem. I used the largest diodes in my random diode collection.

Comment: as long as the diodes can hold the motor current, I'd say you're good